# Apply new log configuration to all containers after daemon restart

Tags: docker

Is there any way the new configuration in `daemon.json` to apply to all the containers after the daemon restarts?

Docker seems to not apply log configuration changes in `daemon.json` to already running containers, **even if the daemon is restarted**:

1. Run a container (c1) with some log configuration in `daemon.json` like `... "max-file": "3" ...`
2. `docker inspect c1` shows the configuration
3. Change the `daemon.json` to `... "max-file": "5" ...`
4. Restart the daemon with `service docker restart`
5. `docker inspect c1` shows the **old** configuration
6. If I run a new container (c2) and `docker inspect c2` the new config applies to this one

I wouldn't expect this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not what you wanted to hear, but...

**That behavior is to be expected. Containers are static from the point of creation in their configuration.**

To underline this statement, here is an example with a storage driver. If you choose another storage driver your current containers won't work anymore. You can find this particular info here:

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/#shared-storage-systems-and-the-storage-driver

> Important: When you change the storage driver, any existing images and
>   containers become inaccessible. This is because their layers cannot be
>   used by the new storage driver. If you revert your changes, you will
>   be able to access the old images and containers again, but any that
>   you pulled or created using the new driver will then be inaccessible.

---

To role out the changes that you have done in your deamon you need to recreate all containers on the system.

**Save your data**

Do you have the data stored in named volumes or hostpath volumes? If so you should be fine, otherwise you can copy any data that you need out of the containers with

```
docker cp container:/path/to/files /target/folder/on/host
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

if you use an orchestrator you could e.g. drain the node, which terminates all containers on the host and after successful draining add the node back to the cluster. The concrete command would depend on the orchestrator of your choice.

---

### Update

**Question**: I don't understand how the data volumes can be related to the log configuration. If I had data stored in named volumes or host path volumes I would be fine, but I didn't see the relation to my question.

**Answer**: Correct, functionality-wise, the info regarding volumes is just added for you such that you do not lose data unknowingly / unrecoverably.

Comment: I'm not using any orchestrator. I don't understand how the data volumes can be related to the log configuration.

Comment: If you do not use an orchestrator my answer still holds true.What do you mean by "data volumes"?

Comment: I mean docker volumes. You said if I had data stored in named volumes or hostpath volumes I would befine, but I didn't see the relaton to my question. I get now that you are talking about the re-creation and the way to keep the data. No problem with that. Sad to hear there is no ither way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, this is not possible. It will overwrite the static property of a container. Any changes in daemon.json just a reload is fine, restart is not required. A Restart will kill your old containers if `live-restore property` is not set.

Coming to a probable solution list which you can do. 
- You can restart your old containers manually if they dont affect you, certainly after your config reload on the daemon.

 - You can run another container, a duplicate, slowly move traffic and get away from the old container - if you do not need static data and logs to be carried forward to new container.

 - You manually take back up of your running container, i mean save your container using `docker save`, kill it, then load your container using `docker load` to bring back a new container with your container data.

 - if you never wish to restart your container, not even a blue green way, then run another container - a log roller service from apache or your own implementation, link that container to your running container so it gets access to your old container data, then start pulling out logs or perform housekeeping.

 Above are the option i could think of now. If you get a hook of a better way, i am eager to learn that.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you elaborate on this: _- You can restart your old containers manually if they dont affect you, certainly after your config reload on the daemon._ 
You mean that restarting the daemon and the container should apply the changes? I didn't have that feeling.

Comment: no. reload the daemon and manually restart the containers. Its most similar to kill container and start them again.

Answer (score 0):

I did an edit to the /etc/docker/daemon.json file , the number of log files to keep , and their size, and then I did a docker
`container restart name-of-cont`
and the container restarted without using the new values, so I was frustrated, but then I thought to try to do a

```
docker container stop name-of-cont
```

and then (after more than 10 secs)

```
docker container start name-of-cont
```

and the change was really there,as I could see from

```
docker container inspect name-of-cont | grep max-
```